# Load a cluster layer using Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a Tile server developed in JavaScript using express. [Here you can see the code.](https://pastebin.com/63XKJWPk)

But I would like to know if its possible to load a cluster layer created using Mapbox and tiles to cluster layer. With GeoJSON file works perfectlty but with tiles, render all circles but circle-color and circle-radius doesnt work.

All circles are equal and black by default.

My code:

```
<script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10',
            center: [-103.59179687498357, 40.66995747013945],
            zoom: 3
        });

        map.on('load', function () {

            map.addSource('clustersource', {
                type: 'vector',
                tiles: ['http://192.168.240.71:8090/tile/terremotos_3e7010c6_2ac0_4895_a392_8dfe212c113f/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'],
                cluster: true,
                clusterMaxZoom: 14,
                clusterRadius: 50 
            });

            map.addLayer({
                id: 'clusters',
                type: 'circle',
                source: 'clustersource',
                'source-layer': 'terremotos_3e7010c6_2ac0_4895_a392_8dfe212c113f',
                paint: {
                    'circle-color': [
                        "step",
                        ["get", "point_count"],
                        "#51bbd6",
                        100,
                        "#f1f075",
                    ],
                    'circle-opacity': 1,
                    'circle-radius': [
                        'step',
                        ["get", "point_count"],
                        20,
                        100,
                        30
                    ]
                },
                layout: {
                    visibility: 'visible'
                }
            });


        });
    </script>
```